# Inhomogeneous Airy equation $y'' + t y = \cos(t) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, airy-functions

So, given the initial equation as $y'' + t y = \cos(t) $, I've got no clue as to how to handle this one.

I did some research into it, $y'' + xy =0 $ is an Airy equation that can be perfectly solved by different methods, i.e. series, Airy functions etc. Still, when it comes to an inhomogeneous guy, I am baffled. 
What do I do? 
I tried to utilize a series approach, but got stuck with the cosine $ t^{2n}$ part of the series 
$$
2a_2 -1 +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} t^n \left( \left(n+2\right)\left(n+1\right)a_{n+2}+a_{n-1} - \frac{\left(-1\right)^n t^n} {(2n)!}\right) = 0
$$ 
So it's of no use to me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did your last expression come from? When searching for a series solution you are supposed to explicitly write power series on both sides and carefully match coefficients.

Let's assume, for small $t$, the function can be written as:

$$y(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2 t^2+ \cdots$$

Now we substitute this into the equation.

Up to first order we have: $$2a_2+6 a_3 t+a_0 t=1$$ Up to second order: $$2a_2+6 a_3 t+12 a_4 t^2+a_0 t+a_1 t^2=1-\frac{1}{2} t^2$$ and so on. Now we match the coefficients for the same powers of $t$. We can see here that: $$2a_2=1 \\ 6a_3+a_0=0 \\ 12 a_4+a_1=-\frac{1}{2}$$

If there's a general pattern, we can try to derive it. It's not always clear from the start, which is why I prefer writing down the first few terms explicitly.

In any case, I don't see what kind of trouble you had with your general expression? Yes, series for $\cos$ have only even powers. That just makes the equations easier to solve.

Note that we can write the cosine series as:

$$\cos t=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n t^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_n t^n}{n!}$$

Where $c_{2k}=(-1)^k$ and $c_{2k+1}=0$, for $n=2k$ or $n=2k+1$.

Can you match the coefficients for your equation now?

---

**Update**

Another way would be to use the standard methods of solving inhomogeneous linear ODEs.

We search for a particular solution $y_p$, and write the general solution as a sum of the general solution of homogeneous equation $y_h$ and $y_p$.

$$y(t)=y_h(t)+y_p(t)$$

$$y_h(t)=C_1 \text{Ai} (-t)+C_2 \text{Bi} (-t)$$

Searching for $y_p$ might be done in various ways, for example, search in the form:

$$y_p(t)=C(t) \text{Ai} (-t)$$

Then:

$$C''\text{Ai} (-t) -2 C' \text{Ai}' (-t)= \cos t$$

Set:

$$C'(t)=f(t)$$

$$\text{Ai} (-t) f'-2 \text{Ai}' (-t) f= \cos t$$

This is a first order linear equation and can be solved in the usual way.

Of course, this method leads to some very awkward integrals, but it gives exact general solution in a manner of speaking.

Comment: I was as general as possible
Went all the way from $y\left(t \right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n t $ hence $y''\left(t\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_n t^{n-2} $
With some simplifications, I got $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(n+2\right)\left(n+1\right)a_{n+2} t^{n}+ a_2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n-1} t^{n} $ on the left side of the equation, leaving that cosine series on the right

Comment: @Simullacra, so what is your problem with cosine series again? I don't understand. It's just an ordinary power series, you match the coefficients like usual. Anyway, see my edit for another standard method

Comment: @Simullacra, if you get confused by the general expression, just take my advice, and write down the first few terms of the series (up to some power of $t$) explicitly

Comment: I don't seem to get your transformation of the series, where you got $t^n$ instead of $t^{2n}$

Comment: @Simullacra, it's just a change of index. I add odd powers of $t$ with zero coefficients, then rename the index... Anyway, just write down a few term explicitly and see that it's true.

Comment: Well, it's clearer now. Anyways, I've only managed to find recurrent formulas for $a_{2k}$ and $a_{2k+1}$ being respectively $ a_{2k+2}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k} -a_{2k-1}(2 k)! }{(2 k+2)!}$ and  $a_{2k+3}=-\frac{a_{2 k}}{(2 k+2) (2 k+3)}$
And when further in I try to find closed forms for two sums, I get nothing. It's so deeply entwined together(the sums, the coefficients etc) that I've got no idea.

Comment: @Simullacra, I didn't check, but it's normal that you have different formulas for even and odd terms. You can check by substitution into the equation

Comment: Yeah, well, don't get me wrong, but that's the actual problem. I can compute the coefficients this way, but I can't find a way to simplify it to any closed-form sums. Like, I should (I guess) get something like $y\left(t\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n t^n=... a_0 \sum + a_1 \sum $. And that's the tragedy. I'm sorry for being dumb tho.

Comment: @Simullacra, you are not always going to find the closed form for anything. In fact, most problems do not lead to closed form solutions. Having your sum be separated into even and odd terms is absolutely fine and acceptable. You should focus on practical things, like whether or not it's convenient to calculate the function that way, and for which range of the variable